# How to customize QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qcalendarwidget

I'm trying to apply some stylesheets to my `QCalendarWidget`, and I already made some changes. Here is my code at the moment:

```
QCalendarWidget QWidget{
background-color:magenta;
color: green;

}

QCalendarWidget QToolButton{
background-color:black;
color: green;
icon-size: 30px;
}

QCalendarWidget QMenu{
background-color:magenta;
color: green;

}

QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView:enabled{
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
}

QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView:disabled{
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
}

QCalendarWidget QMenu{
    background-color: rgb(255, 46, 221);
}

QCalendarWidget QSpinBox{
    background-color: black;
}
```

And the result is this:

[image: image 1]

The problem is that I can't find how I customize the green arrows, the number of the week, and the days of the week. Any suggestions?

Comment: Explain better, what do you want to change from the green arrows? What do you want to change in the "number of the week" and "days of the week"?

Comment: I want to change the green arrow's icon and background and the background, font size and style from the number of the week and days of the week.

Answer (score 2):

This only works for month buttons, is a bit hacky, and keep in mind that it's based on hardcoded private methods. It uses the objectName to get the specific QToolButton ("qt_calendar_prevmonth" and "qt_calendar_nextmonth") and also set the icon. Do not use `image: url`, as it won't work for QToolButtons.

Theoretically you could also find their object names by going through the layout of the header and check the first and last QToolButtons, which might be a bit "harder", but probably safer, and, after that, you set the stylesheet accordingly.

```css
#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    background-color: blue;
    icon-size: 30px;
    qproperty-icon: url(prevmonth.svg);
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    background-color: orange;
    icon-size: 30px;
    qproperty-icon: url(nextmonth.svg);
}
```

Unfortunately, due to the way QCalendarWidget works, there's no way to change the format of "headers" through stylesheet, so you'll need to stick to QCalendarWidget's headerTextFormat(), dateTextFormat() and so on.

```
fmt = cal.headerTextFormat()
fmt.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('green'))
fmt.setBackground(QtGui.QColor('orange'))
cal.setHeaderTextFormat(fmt)
```